# Problem with inserting sound and movie in Powerpoint presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I use Microsoft Office 2007 and I have a presentation with both sound and movie inserted, but when I move this to other computers (with the sound and movie files in the same folder as the presentation is) I have to re-insert them again because they don't start automatically.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sounds/Movies don't play, images disappear or links break when I move or email a presentation](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00155.htm)

> You create a presentation that includes linked images, sounds or movies. Everything looks perfect, so you email the presentation to someone else, burn a CD of it or just move it to a different folder on your own computer.
>   And now nothing works. Powerpoint displays a missing graphic icon instead of your pictures or it won't play your sounds and movies.